# How to send data from one site and receive it on another in php

Tags: php, curl, send, transfer

I have data in string format in a single variable in a php file on a wordpress site.
I want to fetch that variable's value through a php file on different server.

I want a way which will send that variable to my receiving php file that I have created on different server and print that values here.

In short, e.g. let there is data in      mydomain1.com/send.php 
which need to be stored or displayed in mydomain2.com/receive.php

But, **without using form**.There is no html form in sending file and also I don't want it since no redirection should be done.Just on a function execution in sending file data need to be transferred and displayed only on receiving end.

(I tried to find out solution for this using cURL.But, everywhere I found code to send data but what about receiving data, how can I capture that sent data and display at receiving end.)
If there is another solution except cURL or form submission I would appreciate.

Please help soon.

Comment: Use anchror (`<a href="..."></a>`) to send your variable through `GET`.

Answer (score 1):

there are a lot of ways to do this, one way would be a [SOAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) client/server solution..:

you have basically 2 php files, one file on server1 is let say the client.php and on the other server there is the file named server.php which will receive all the data sent from client.php on server 1... here is a simple source, you need to change the URLs in the script to your server/client URLs so it works..:

**client.php**

```
<?php
//This is the SOAP Client which will call a method on Server 2 with passing some data:
//uri is the location where client.php is located, and "location" is the exact location to the client, including the name "client.php"

$client=new SoapClient(NULL,array("uri"=>"http://localhost/test","location"=>"http://localhost/test/test.php"));
$message=$client->hello("Hello World");
echo($message);
?>
```

**server.php**

```
<?php
//This is the SOAP Server
class server2{
    public function hello($data){
        return "I received following data: " . $data;
    }
}

//the URI here is the location where the server.php is located.
$settings = array("uri"=>"http://localhost/test/");
$s=new SoapServer(null,$settings);
$s->setClass("server2");
$s->handle();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial: http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl

Basically you can send the urlencoded values using `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`

Comment: I looked to that solution earlier but I think I did not clearly get it.Because, this code is for one php file (send.php in my case).But, how can I retrieve and display data sent in my receiving php file(receive.php in my case).If I put 'echo $result' in my receive file then it will display a boolean value not data fetched.

Comment: try `var_dump( $_POST )` in your receiving.php file.
The sent variables should be available via `$_POST`...

Comment: I have already tried var_dump($_POST) but this displays output on the sending file itself even I write this statement in receiving file.Receiving file displays blank array.Another thing, **send file** **should not display** output.